# Why xmlns:xsi, and not only xsi in XML documents?

Tags: xml, xml-namespaces

I understand that, by convention, the default namespace is named `xmlns` attribute in the root element of an XML document. Other namespaces are named other names. Now, I wonder why is XML Scheme Instance namespace always named `xmlns:xsi` and not simply `xsi`? Would `xsi` be the same as `xmlns:xsi`? If yes, why yes? If no, why no?

Elements and attribute names not coming from the default namespace are always preceded by name of the namespace. Having `xmlns:xsi` tells me that `xsi` is an attribute defined in namespace `xmlns`, which is conflicting, since the attribute names from the default namespace shouldn't be preceded by the namespace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default namespace is not named `xmlns`.

`xmlns` is the way to declare a namespace *prefix* (i.e. short name, handle). The syntax is `xmlns[:prefix]="namepace-uri"`.

There can be exactly one namespace declaration per XML element where you are allowed to leave off the prefix (`xmlns="namespace-uri"`), and if it is declared that way, it is called the *default namespace*.

It's called *default* because all descendant elements that don't explicitly override it will inherit it - here `<element>`, `<child>` and the first `<grandchild>` are all part of `some_namespace`:

```
<element xmlns="some_namespace">
  <child>
    <grandchild />
    <grandchild xmlns="something_else" />
    <yan:grandchild xmlns:yan="yet_another_namespace" />
  </child>
</element>
```

This automatic inheritance does not happen with prefixes - here, only `<sn:element>` is in `some_namespace`, and therefore identical to the `<element>` above, while `<child>` and the first `<grandchild>` are in no namespace:

```
<sn:element xmlns:sn="some_namespace">
  <child>
    <grandchild />
    <grandchild xmlns="something_else" />
    <yan:grandchild xmlns:yan="yet_another_namespace" />
  </child>
</sn:element>
```

The important part is only the namespace URI, not the prefix:

- `xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"` declares that the URI `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance` shall be known as `xsi` inside this element.
- You are free to choose any prefix you like, you can declare `xmlns:bob="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"` and that would mean that the URI `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance` shall be known as `bob` inside this element.

By convention, many widely-used XML namespace URIs get the same prefix everywhere, but that's not technically necessary.

Comment: "`xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"` declares that the URI 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' shall be known as `xsi` inside this element.". Does it mean that `xsi` is now a namespace whose elements now can be used within the document? If yes, what is the scope? The element in which it was defined or the whole document?

Comment: `xsi` is not a namespace. `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance` is the namespace. `xsi` is merely the short name for that namespace, commonly called "prefix" because you write it as a prefix before elements you want to be in the associated namespace. The scope of a namespace declaration is the element that it appears on and everything inside.

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant, but didn't express myself properly. I meant the namespace represented by the name, i.e., by `xsi`. Thank you very much for the clarification.

Comment: Readers falling in this question may be looking for the actual purpose of xsi / xsd prefixes, which by convention, refer to XML Schema Document and XML Schema Instance, and the answer is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41035128/what-is-the-difference-between-xsd-and-xsi