# XSLT - XSD files - Where to find the schema.xsd file - Please suggest

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd

Please make me understand where to find the schema.xsd file which is mentioned in the code.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 


xmlns:vmf="http://www.altova.com/MapForce/UDF/vmf" 


xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 


exclude-result-prefixes="vmf xs">


<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>



<xsl:template match="/">


<DATA>


<xsl:attribute name="xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation" 

namespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

schema.xsd


</xsl:attribute>


<ITEMS>


</ITEMS>


</xsl:Stylesheet>
```

Comment: You don't need to access that file; most of the time, the url isn't valid, or publicly accessible; maybe this is a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Thanks @RubensFarias Just thought of looking into the xsd file for the schema definitions. if it is a physical file plz suggest where it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the XML Schema for Schemas [**here**](https://www.w3.org/2009/XMLSchema/XMLSchema.xsd).

However, you probably do not need it unless you're trying to validate an XSD (as opposed to validating an XML document instance with against an XSD).

**See also:**

- [xmlns, xmlns:xsi, xsi:schemaLocation, and targetNamespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34202967/290085)
- [How to link XML to XSD using schemaLocation or noNamespaceSchemaLocation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35411871/290085)
- [Must an XML namespace name URI be retrievable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27613891/290085)
- [What is the difference between xsd and xsi?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41035128/290085)
- [How to restrict the value of an XML element using xsi:type in XSD?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33808790/290085)